# Extract value of single string record from PostgreSQL JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

For a given Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."store" (
    "key" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "value" json,
    PRIMARY KEY ("key")
);
```

If I populate the following JSON encoded values:

```
INSERT INTO "store" VALUES ('integer', '1'),
    ('array', '{"foo": "bar"}'),
    ('string', '"baz"');
```

I can write a query to extract the value of foo like so:

```
SELECT value->>'foo' FROM store WHERE key = 'array'
```

And it returns the string value of bar (with no quotes).

However, I cannot figure it out is how should I write the query to get the unencoded value of the string key. The following query returns "baz" (with quotes).

```
SELECT value FROM store WHERE key = 'string'
```

How should I write this last query to extract the single string value of the 'string' key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `#>>` operator, from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html): `Get JSON object at specified path as text`.

```
SELECT value #>>'{}' FROM store WHERE key = 'string'
```

Result: `baz` and not `"baz".`

---

EDIT:

You can also do the same when `key = 'array'`:

```
SELECT value #>>'{foo}' FROM store WHERE key = 'array'
```